# How can I generate an x509 RSA-PSS certificate with openssl whose trailer field contains the value 0xBC meet the RFC8017

Tags: openssl, rsa, x509

With the Windows version of openssl(3.2.1) we want to generate a certificate with these conditions:

```
Hash method: SHA-256
Mask Generation Function: MGF1 with SHA-256
Length of the salt: 32 bytes
Trailer Field: 0xBC
```

The specified parameters correspond to the specifications of the RSASSA-PSS signature scheme as described in RFC 8017

Unfortunately, a certificate is always generated that contains the value 0x01 in the trailer field.

Steps:

1. Generate Key
   `openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa-pss -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096  -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_md:sha256 -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_mgf1_md:sha256  -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_saltlen:32 -out 20240314_privateKey.pem`
2. Generate certifikat
   `openssl req -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096 -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:32 -key 20240314_privateKey.pem -out 20240314_certifcate.pem`
3. Display certificate
   `openssl x509 -in 20240314_certifcate.pem -text`

Result
...
Mask Algorithm: mgf1 with sha256
Salt Length: 0x20
Trailer Field: 0x01 (default)
...

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The encoded trailer field value of `01` corresponds to a trailer value of `BC`.  As the only legal value (to my knowledge), everyone writes an `01` there, corresponding to everyone using `BC` in the EMSA-PSS steps.

From https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.2.3:

> trailerField
>
> is the trailer field number, for compatibility with
> IEEE 1363a [IEEE1363A].  It SHALL be 1 for this version of the
> document, which represents the trailer field with hexadecimal
> value 0xbc.  Other trailer fields (including the trailer field
> HashID || 0xcc in IEEE 1363a) are not supported in this document.
>
> TrailerField ::= INTEGER { trailerFieldBC(1) }